# Biztalk Server 2006 HTML Email with inline images

Tags: html, email, image, biztalk, inline

I m quite new in Biztalk Server 2006 and I have a problem regarding sending HTML Email with inline images. What I have do so far is sending HTML emails (or text emails) in BizTalk without embedded images which works.

Could somebody help me with this?
Thank you very much for your efforts!

Br, Toan

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending an HTML message, then it is just the case of adding the

The issue then is that you need to save the image on a public internet address (assuming that the message goes outside the firewall) or on a server in your intranet that everyone can access.

An example of the image tag would be:

```
<img src="http://mylocalserver/images/myimage.jpg" /> This is the internal server example
```

or

```
<img src="http://myexternalserver.com/images/myimage.jpg" /> This is the external server example
```

Hopefuly this helps.

Comment: Hi Silveira 

Thanky you very much for you feedback. What I m looking for is to have inline images in HTML Body with e.g. CID. The client uses a webservice of the biztalk to send the email HTML Body string via soap.

Code snippet of the schema (used by client): 
....
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="From" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Recipient" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="CC" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Subject" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element name="Body" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
...

Thank you,Toan